# R extracting variable mapping from table matrix

Tags: r, linear-algebra

This is a bit of a brain teaser here - I could do this by hand, but there must be a linear algebra way to do this.

I have used the table function to come up with a dataframe/matrix that has the counts of the coincidence two variables:

```
>table(gfk_data$AnswerID, gfk_data$AnswerText)


          Very unlikely Unlikely Somewhat likely Very likely
  1161841             0        0               0        3029
  1161842             0        0             175           0
  1161843             0      165               0           0
  1161844           562        0               0           0
  1161845             0        0               0          31
  1161846             0        0              26           0
  1161847             0       26               0           0
  1161848            45        0               0           0
```

How can I get the mapping of AnswerIDs which are the row names to AnswerText that are the column headers?

Maybe this is easer to extract from the original dataframe?

The desired result would be something like:

```
AnswerID  AnswerText   
1161841   Very likely
1161842   Somewhat likely
1161843   Unlikely
...
```

So far I can think of using a loop to look up the values of AnswerText for each AnswerID in the original data frame and inserting the `unique()` of that return into dataframe.  That will certainly work, but maybe there is something more elegant?

Comment: could you post a sample of your desired result? what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `as.data.frame.table()` and extract the first two columns where the third column is greater than 0:

```
as.data.frame.table(
    table(gfk_data$AnswerID, gfk_data$AnswerText)
    )[as.data.frame.table(table(gfk_data$AnswerID, gfk_data$AnswerText))[,3] > 0, c(1,2)]
```

Comment: Yeah, that seems like the way that's easiest to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Another option using @lmo's `df` is

```
data.frame(answerID=rownames(df),answerText=names(df)[apply(df,1,which.max)])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to get it from the output above. The "trick" in constructing the first column is to use a lookup table that pulls the proper row names by the maximum value for each column.

```
dfNew <- data.frame(answerID=rownames(df)[max.col(df)],
                    answerText=names(df), stringsAsFactors=F)

  answerID      answerText
1 1161844   Very_unlikely
2 1161843        Unlikely
3 1161842 Somewhat_likely
4 1161841     Very_likely
5 1161844   Very_unlikely
6 1161843        Unlikely
7 1161842 Somewhat_likely
8 1161841     Very_likely
```

.
The data.frame can be re-sorted using `order`

```
dfNew <- dfNew[order(dfNew$answerID),]
dfNew
  answerID      answerText
4  1161841     Very_likely
8  1161841     Very_likely
3  1161842 Somewhat_likely
7  1161842 Somewhat_likely
2  1161843        Unlikely
6  1161843        Unlikely
1  1161844   Very_unlikely
5  1161844   Very_unlikely
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(header=T, text="         Very_unlikely Unlikely Somewhat_likely Very_likely
1161841             0        0               0        3029
1161842             0        0             175           0
1161843             0      165               0           0
1161844           562        0               0           0
1161845             0        0               0          31
1161846             0        0              26           0
1161847             0       26               0           0
1161848            45        0               0           0")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could put the resulting matrix into a dataframe and then filter based on item frequencies greater than 0.

```
count_df <- as.data.frame(table(gfk_data$AnswerID, gfk_data$AnswerText))
count_df[count_df$Freq>1,]
```

and the first two columns of that dataframe would give me my desired result

```
      Var1            Var2 Freq
4  1161844   Very unlikely  562
8  1161848   Very unlikely   45
11 1161843        Unlikely  165
15 1161847        Unlikely   26
18 1161842 Somewhat likely  175
22 1161846 Somewhat likely   26
25 1161841     Very likely 3029
29 1161845     Very likely   31
```